# matching fragment of a column value with another column value in R

Tags: r, match

I want to match an original ID with a new ID which is only a fragment of the original ID and return all of the original IDs. Ex. For a data.frame `dat`, `OrigID` is a column name. ID value is `XXX_X_XXX` and the new ID is only the last portion after the underscore sign `_`, which is `XXX`. How can I match this?

I'm not sure how to return only the fragment. I think this returns all hits and not just the portion after the '_' giving me too many values. I also want to place NA values in the vector wherever the ID's don't match.

Ex.

```
IDdat <- read.csv("OrigID.csv")
data <- read.csv("data.csv")
subjects <- unique(data$ID)
IDlist <- c()

for (i in 1:length(subjects)) {
OrigID <- grep(subjects[i], IDdat$ID, value = TRUE)
IDlist <- rbind(IDlist, data.frame(OrigID)
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: This is still not clear to me. Could you show an actual example along with the expected output?

Comment: As far as I understand from your question, new_ID is the substring of OrigID after the last `_`. I'm not sure how they can match or be the same.

Comment: `match(substr(OrigID,7,9), new_ID)` or something similar I imagine, but we're all guessing without proper example data.

Comment: An example would be: OrigID = 123_X_333 and I want to match to the new ID which would be 333 only. I want to return all of the OrigIDs into a vector.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `grep`

```
grep(new_ID, colnames(dat))
```

Comment: When I use grep it tells me argument pattern has length > 1 and only the first element will be used

Comment: @user6210879  Please update your post with a reproducible example